# www.*example*.com works, but not *example*.com - how do it get it to work?

Tags: domain-name-system, http

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJfwN.png

I can go to http://www.*example*.com and www.*example*.com just fine.
The name servers seem to be setup ok.

However, I cannot go to http://*example*.com or *example*.com

I imagine i need to do something with the "records" or something. I am truely lost and I would greatly appreciate any feedback on what I should do.

EDIT: im using nginx, jetty, amazonwebservices, and ubuntu if it matters

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you haven't completely configured your nameserver yet.

Your image shows that you don't have a DNS entry for `example.com` - you only have an entry for `www.example.com`. The [Interstate53 FAQ](https://interstate53.com/faq) has instructions on how to add the entry.

Note that when you add a new A record using the web interface, the `name` field is optional. Leave it blank to define a record for `example.com`.

Comment: it appeared to me that the namefield was mandatory. But like you said, it was optional. It is working great now, thank you so much!

Comment: No worries, glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

Given you state the DNS records appear OK, most likely it is a configuration issue with your web server.

Web servers often use Name-based virtual hosting, so most likely it is configured to use www.example.com but not example.com - within Apache2 this is defined under "ServerAlias", not sure if you have Apache sitting in front of your nginx or not, but either way you need to add an 'alias' of mysite.com to whichever is your front-line webserver.

Comment: Ok, I'll try messing around with nginx because I'm not actually using Apache at all. Thanks for the help!!!!

Comment: I think Tom's solution is actually more correct, try his first.. if it's still a problem then I would look at what I stated.